# Php syntax echo error

Tags: php, html, sql, web-deployment-project

I am trying to get my form to show with queried results being displayed so that the end user can edit them. How can I write my form input value so it echo's the result versus the code?

```
############### PAGE HEADER ###############
     echo '<div id="header">
     <h1> <span id="logo"><img src="/images/twh_logo2.jpg" /></span><span 
     id="title"></span> </h1>
     </div>' . "\r";

    ############### UN-VERIFIED PICK TICKETS###############
     echo '<div id="full">
    <h1> 
     <div class="title">Edit Label Details</div>
    <div id="search" class="text">
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            ID:<br>
            <input type="text" name="id" value= $result[\'id\'];"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</h1>
</div>' . "\r";
  ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to ask a question that people can answer. Simply dumping your code and asking for help isn't enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Interrupt your string:

```
echo '<div id="full">
    ....
    <input type="text" name="id" value="' . $result['id'] . '"><br>
    ....
</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly.

Comment: You might mark the answer as solution if it solved your problem.